# Expo Publish: Request failed with status code 413

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm trying to publish a project in expo using React Native and Windows 10, It's showing me this error every time and I can't find any clear fixes as of yet, has anyone else had this issue? Full error below

```
expo publish --release-channel staging

- Expo SDK: 40.0.0
- Release channel: staging
- Workflow: Managed

Building optimized bundles and generating sourcemaps...
Starting Metro Bundler
Finished building JavaScript bundle in 15886ms.

Bundle                     Size
┌ index.ios.js          1.72 MB
├ index.android.js      1.73 MB
├ index.ios.js.map      5.18 MB
└ index.android.js.map  5.19 MB

� JavaScript bundle sizes affect startup time. Learn more: https://expo.fyi/javascript-bundle-sizes

Analyzing assets
Saving assets
uploading \app\components\pexelsintro.mp4
uploading \app\assets\WDD-logo.png
uploading \app\assets\icon.png
Request failed with status code 413
Error: Request failed with status code 413
    at createError (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:16:15)
    at settle (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:17:12)
    at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\http.js:260:11)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1252:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of js bundle + assets is limited, I don't remember exactly, but it's something around 40-50 MB. I'm assuming that `pexelsintro.mp4` is responsible for exceeding that in your case. You need to either limit size of published assets somehow or self-host it (https://docs.expo.io/distribution/hosting-your-app/). If you don't need OTA updates you can serve that bundle from local machine with something like `ngrok` and kill server after the build, but make sure to disable updates in that case.